# Difference between "guardar" and "resguardar"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I need to translate the sentence *keep confidential information*.  Which should I use, *guardar* or *resguardar*?

Answer (score 2):

In this case *keep* make references to *guardar* or *mantener*, the translation could be *mantenga la información confidencial*

***mantener*** (from [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OH45BSY))

> Del lat. manu tenēre 'tener en la mano'.
>
> Conjug. c. tener.
>
> - tr. Conservar algo en su ser, darle vigor y permanencia.
> - tr. Proseguir en lo que se está ejecutando. Mantener la conversación, el juego.
> - tr. Sostener un torneo, una justa, etc.
> - tr. Der. Amparar a alguien en la posesión o goce de algo.
> - prnl. Perseverar, no variar de estado o resolución.

***guardar***

> De guarda.
>
> - tr. Tener cuidado de algo o de alguien, vigilarlo y defenderlo. Guardar un campo, un rebaño. Guardar a un niño.
> - tr. Poner algo donde esté seguro. Guardar dinero, joyas, vestidos, etc.
> - tr. Observar o cumplir aquello a lo que se está obligado. Guardar la ley, la palabra, el secreto.
> - tr. **Mantener**, observar. Guardar silencio.

Answer (score 2):

`Guardar` is the perfect translation to `save`, means exactly the same.

> Example: I have to save my sculpture in a better place
>
> Debo guardar mi escultura en un sitio mejor*

In the other hand you have `resguardar`, which means to `put something in safeguard`. The translation depends on the context you use it, so it could be translated as: `guard`, `shelter` or even `save` too.

> Example: I need to put in safeguard my car to protect them from wind storm
>
> *Tengo que salvaguardar (proteger, mantener) mi coche para protegerlo del >temporal de viento*

`Resguardar` is normally used when you want to protect some object of any external factor to safeguard it from the damage or avoid their spoil.

In your case, I would use save or protect (to emphasize that the information is important, save maybe isn't enough powerful in this case).

Hope it clarify more your mind.

Answer (score 1):

It would be "resguardar información confidencial" since you'll be actively doing it - keeping it safe.

"Guardar" is used when you put something away.